# Usando JWT com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token, jwt

Galera, estou usando O JWT para gerar TOKEN de acessos ao meu sistema...
Até aqui está ok, estou conseguindo chamar minha API e a mesma me retornar um Token.

O problema está no seguinte cenário.
- Minha intenção é trabalhar com API na minha aplicação Web e iria reutilizar essa mesma API no Mobile.
- Usando o JWT eu estou gerando um TOKEN porém na minha aplicação WEB eu preciso redirecionar o usuario que não possui esse Token para tela de LOGIN assim ele vai gerar o TOKEN e ser redirecionado para a pagina INDEX da WEB. (Já no aplicativo o tratamento é diferente e nao vem o caso aqui.. )

O Meu problema é que eu não consigo redirecionar o meu usuário da WEB para a pagina INDEX do meu sistema...

A Dúvida é o meu Token eu preciso setar em algum lugar? Criar uma sessao e salvar esse token nele? ou o que eu faço?

A minha Rota está da seguinte maneira...

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
      return response()->json(['message' => 'Jobs API', 'status' => 'Connected']);;
    });

    Route::post('/auth/login', 'UsuarioController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
        Route::post('logout', 'AuthenticateController@logout');

        Route::get('/teste', function() {
            return response()->json(['foo' => 'bar']);
        });
    });    
});
```

Lá na classe HomeController eu coloquei no construct

```
$this->middleware('jwt.auth');
```

Porém sempre que entro na pagina principal do meu site já exibe a mensagem:

```
{"error":"token_not_provided"}
```

A minha função que faz o Login está abaixo:

```
public function login(AuthenticateRequest $request) {        
      // Get only email and password from request
      $credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'senha');

      // Get user by email
      $user = User::where('usuario', $credentials['usuario'])->first();
      // $company = DB::table('empresas_funcionario')->where('usuario', $credentials['usuario'])->first();

      // Validate Company
      if(!$user) {
        return response()->json([
          'result' => false,
          'error' => Lang::get('messages.userInvalid')
        ], 401);
      }

      // Validate Password
      if (md5($credentials['senha']) != $user->senha ) {
          return response()->json([
            'result' => false,
            'error' => Lang::get('messages.passInvalid')
          ], 401);
      }

      // Generate Token
      $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

      // Get expiration time
      $objectToken = JWTAuth::setToken($token);
      // $expiration = JWTAuth::decode($objectToken->getToken())->get('exp');

      return response()->json([
        'com' => $user,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'gestor'
      ]);
    }
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém passou por isso e como que posso fazer para que após a pessoa logar pela Web seja redirecionada para a pagina do Index e/ou como que faço para identificar se o token foi criado assim eu jogo ele para a tela de Login ou se não jogo para o Index....

Agradeço a ajuda...

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se você já conseguiu, resolver, mas mesmo assim, vou deixar aki..

Você tem que informar o token para o sistema , e isso pode ser feito na url http://seu_dominio/seu_controller/sua_acao?token=token_gerado_na_variavel_access_token

:)